# How do I use helper functions Inline within React Components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Given the following simple React component, how do I pass the props through a helper function, e.g. to tidy up units/scaling.

```
var h = require ('../../helpers/helper.js');
export default class TableSingleLine extends React.Component {
  render () {
   return (
     <tr>
          <td>
            {h.formatPrice(this.props.Data.price)}
        </td>
  </tr>
}
}
```

Variations of this approach fail with TypeError: h.formatPrice is not a function

Thanks!

Comment: Check the export of `helper.js` as the rest of your code is fine.

Comment: Thanks, this led to the problem.